# Bind: (Reverse) zone not loaded due to errors

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bind, reverse-dns

Using Ubuntu Server and bind9...

Here's the error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPjEl.png)

Direct zone:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQcBu.png)

Reverse zone:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydtgQ.png)

Named.conf.local:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xcSfI.png)

Named.conf.options:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8GJur.png)

When i do the checkconf and the checkzones it says everything is good, basically... But when i try to nslookup an IP it fails. Fortunately, it does not happens with the direct resolution... Please help!

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Please  use copy-paste and avoid posting screenshots of text when posting console output / settings. Format that text  as "`code`" using [Markdown](https://serverfault.com/editing-help) and/or the formatting options in the edit menu to properly type-set your posts. That improves readability, attracts better answers  and allows indexing by search engines, which may help people with similar questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can (manually) check the syntax of a zone file with the [`named-checkzone`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/named-checkzone) command. Which is also what currently happens during bind start-up and generates a fault.

For the reverse zone that generates the error use for example

```
named-checkzone 12.168.192.in-addr.arpa. etc/bind/db.12.168.192.in-addr.arpa.
```

That will show you the complete error messages that prevent Bind from loading that zone.

I suspect that the problem is in how you're attempting to use  short hostnames as FQDN's. Generally any resource record that ends in a trailing `.` dot is considered a FQDN and the FQDN's  you entered in the reverse zone such as `ubuntusymme.`  simply do not exist (those should probably read and match the forward FQDN's you defined, so : `ubuntusymme.inglan.net.` )